# Orthographic View is Curving the Textured Image When It Should be Flat

Tags: rendering, camera, orthographic

I am currently working on a 3d product rendering for a flat, e-commerce style image.
I tried to move the camera close and far from the subject and set the Lens Type to Orthographic, but the image still keeps curving to the sides.

[image: Problem Image]

How do I make the render less Perspective and Flatter like this image.

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: It an orthograohic view but your object is a cylinder, not a flat object, if you want the text to look flat you could unwrap with the Project From View option, have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

It's an orthograohic view but your object is a cylinder, not a flat object, so it's normal to have a flattened text on the sides:

[image]

If you want the text to look flat you could unwrap with the *Project From View* option, here is what it would give:

[image]

But of course it will look stretched on the sides if you change the view:

[image]

Comment: I just tried what you suggested. Thank you very much, this helped a lot.

Comment: EDIT. I came across another issue. When I Projected to View, I got over lapping images. Note: I marked seams for both the Front and Back with the Top and Bottom.

Comment: EDIT: I came across another problem After I 'Project from View.' The two images overlap with one another. NOTE: I marked seams for both the Front and Back View. It's not like I can create separate Materials for each knowing I will include a brushed metal texture. I tried to 'Deselect' the excess faces, but that did not seem to work. 

[![UV Unwrapping Problem][4]][4]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/InEzG.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/209PG.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsvIH.jpg
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dXw5.png

Comment: in orthographic view, choose the front view, select the front faces only, unwrap, put the UV faces over the part of the image you want, then do the same for the back faces, if it still doesn't work, please pack your image and share your object https://blend-exchange.com/